# Getting: Firebase service named 'database' already registered error, even tho I am not importing firebase/database anywhere

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Environment**

- Operating System version: Mac OS 10.15.1
- Firebase SDK version: 8.8.0
- Firebase Product: database (auth, database, storage, etc)
- Node.js version: 8.15.1
- NPM version: 6.9.0
- "firebase": "7.5.0",
- "firebase-admin": "8.8.0",
- "firebase-functions": "3.3.0"

**Problem**

When I call `firebase deploy --only functions`, it stops on step `functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...` and throws:

`database: Firebase: Firebase service named 'database' already registered (app/duplicate-service)`

This is the where the error is found:
`at error (....../functions/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.node.cjs.js:41:21)`

Also I started getting: `Error parsing triggers: The gRPC binary module was not installed. This may be fixed by running "npm rebuild"`
Of course I have tried `npm rebuild` but without any luck...

**Relevant Code**

The only way I reference database is through:

```
// Init firebase access to DB
const firebase_admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Get a database reference
const firebase_db = firebase_admin.database();
```

I do this in multiple files tho.

After a little more digging, I managed to find out that it is caused by code in these two files:

```
// Init firebase access to DB
const firebase_admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Get a database reference to our blog
const firebase_db = firebase_admin.database();

const get_firebase_data = async (page_type, call_back) => {
  const is_paypal_page = page_type === "paypal"
  const is_admin_page = page_type === "admin"
  const content = await firebase_db.ref("/content").once("value")
  const footer_content = await firebase_db.ref("/footer_content").once("value")
  const header_items = await firebase_db.ref("/header_items").once("value")
  const translations = await firebase_db.ref("/translations").once("value")
  const single_product_homepages = await firebase_db.ref("/single_product_homepages").once("value")
  const couple_products_homepages = await firebase_db.ref("/couple_products_homepages").once("value")
  const categories_of_product_variety = await firebase_db.ref("/categories_of_product_variety").once("value")

  let products;
  let shipping_options;
  let admin;
  if(is_paypal_page || is_admin_page) {
    products = await firebase_db.ref("/products").once("value")
    shipping_options = await firebase_db.ref("/shipping_options").once("value")
  }
  if(is_admin_page)
    admin = await firebase_db.ref("/admin").once("value")

  const final_object = {
     ...
  }

  call_back(null, final_object)
}

module.exports = (req,res) => {
  get_firebase_data(req.params[0].replace("/", ""), (err,result) => {
    if(err) res.send(err)
    res.send(result)
  })
}
```

and

```
const paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk')
const { paypal_config } = require("../config")
const axios_instance = require("./inventorysource/axios_inventorysource_instance")
const create_order = require("./inventorysource/create_order")

paypal.configure(paypal_config)

const paymentPaypal = (paymentID, execute_payment_json, call_back) => {
    paypal.payment.execute(paymentID, execute_payment_json, (error, paymentLog)=> {
      if (error) 
        return call_back(error)
      else {
        call_back(null, paymentLog)
      }
    })
  }


module.exports = (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body
  const execute_payment_json = { "payer_id": body.data.payerID }
  const paymentID = body.data.paymentID

  paymentPaypal(paymentID, execute_payment_json, (err, paypal_data) => {
    if(err)
      res.send(err)
    else
      create_order(
        axios_instance(body.data.is_production),
        body.data.is_production,
        body.data.amount,
        body.data.user_and_product_data,
        res, paypal_data
      )
  })
}
```

However I dont import or require "firebase/database" anywhere in my code.

**What I have tried**

As answers to similar issues suggest, I have deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and tried re-installing with `npm install` multiple times.
I have also tried using different versions od `Node` and completely rebuilding my packages with `npm rebuild`.

Furthermore I have tried installing latest versions of the above mentioned `firebase` packages and then deleting and install npm all over again. Still with no luck...

I also tried commenting out parts of my code that deal with `firebase` but still, the error remains.

Comment: Please edit the post to include the complete, minimal set of code that causes this.  We should be able to reproduce using exactly what you provide in the question.

Comment: @DougStevenson The problem is that I dont know what part of code causes it.
But I will post my index.js, which has all my functions which are being deployed imported.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you should trim your code down to just the minimum that causes the error, then post exactly what that code is. This is part of the debugging process.  It will help you think though where the problem really is, and better communicate to us where exactly you're stick.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As the error seems to occur during local emulation prior to deploying the code, my only guess is that on your development system, you have an outdated version of the Firebase CLI that should also be reinstalled (or a globally installed outdated Firebase SDK that should be removed).

Comment: I want to note that since this question was asked, the Firebase SDK has updated its gRPC dependency to a new implementation that should no longer trigger the error message mentioned in the question.